# Pyspark dataframe spliting columns gives empty result

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split a column and allocate a new column name to split result.
But it gives empty column. Please find below the Expression.

**df.selectExpr("variable_name","split(variable_name, '.')[2] as r").show(100,False)**

I am suppose to get ZZZZ as result column values in a

It gives this [image: result]

Comment: Escaping using  '\\\\.'  worked for me. Thanks !!!

Comment: Can you please share your solution as an answer so that it may be useful for others in the future?

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the comments!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using '\\\\.' to escape the special character and it is working now.

Here is the code:

df.selectExpr("variable_name","split(variable_name, '\\\\.')[2] as r").show(100,False)

Thanks!!